# In javascript, How to deal with a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm facing a problem when i want to send a form with javascript ! In fact the code works well to send the form, but unfortunately i can't find the way to put data in my form.

When we press on the finish button so with no js, it works well and action in bdd is working !

The difference between the 2 methods is with js no Form data in the post request. I've already tried to create a form in using javacript but i can't put the name "Form" into my request ?

So what's the best way ? create a new form with js and send it or use the existent one ? Thanks all

```js
function recuppoint() {
   $.post('../ajax/point.php',{pseudo:pseudo}, function(data) {
      console.log('['+data + ']');
      $('.infos2').html(data);
   var durr =  data.split(" :");
  
   var test = durr[1].split(" ");
    if(test[1]==0){
 $("#Form").submit();
  }
    
 console.log(test[1]);
  
   });
}// End of the function
      
setInterval(recuppoint, 1000);// Refresh it each second
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
?php
if (isset($_POST['Form']))
{I do something with bdd}
?>

<form method="post" id="Form" action="" >  
<button type="submit" name="Form">Finish</button>
</form>
```

To follow your answers guys i try like this and not working !!!!!

I repeat i don't need an ajax to send my form submit works but no data !

```js
$.post('/test.php', $('#Form').serialize());
```

I can add all path i want no request is post with submit a request is post with no data! Can you explain me why the request .submit() is send with no data

Second update : [image: form data headers in chrome]
This picture show you what happened when i post form with the button it's what i need in relation with the bdd !

maybe you can understand well my problem ! When i use js to post : no data in the headers so nothing into chrome i can't see the part you can see on the picture !

Third update :

Jsfiddle : {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

Problem found : no field into my form that' why nothing in the headers

```html
<form method="post" id="Form" action="" >
<input type="hidden" name="Form" value="" /> <!-- Try now! ;) --> 
<button type="submit" name="Form">Finish</button>
<!-- There are no fields here --> 
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to use Javascript to submit the form? Or do you want Javascript to make a request with post data using XHR (Ajax)?

Comment: hey thanks to reply, i already use my ajax request everything works well ! i used it to know customer's baance in real time ... works well, i need when the balance is equal 0 send a form, it's working with my code but i don't have any data in my request with js ,with php when i click the button the form is send with the name Form:

Comment: Someone on jsfiddle give me the right answer to my problem so i give you the answer <form method="post" id="Form" action="" >
   
   <input type="hidden" name="field" value="your_field_value" />
    <!-- Try now! ;) -->
 
  <button   type="submit" name="Form">Terminer une consultation</button>

  
  <!-- There are no fields here -->
    </form>

Answer (score 4):

You can use `serialize()` jQuery method.

Look here:

```
$.post('/your-url', $('form').serialize());
```

You also should not send your form every second with `setInterval`. It would be better using **JavaScript Events**.

In this case you can use `submit` event on your form, like here:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
});
```

To avoid the default browser behaviour (page redirect), you can use `preventDefault()` method that is coming with the event object in your listener callback.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: hey the form can't be send each second dude because it only happen when it's equal to zero so no problem in this case ! i tried your method with $post and unfortunately its not working nothing is send no request post !i have two form on the same page

Comment: It's obvious you should change your jQuery selector with your form ID / class name.

Comment: can you give me an example ? beause i don't really understand ?

Comment: If your form is `<form id="myForm" action="/resource.php" method="POST" />` you can use a jQuery selector more accurate that points to the ID of the tag: `$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {});`. 
By the way, I'm sure that your request is sent but you're not seeing it because you have to analyze your browser requests from the browser console.

Comment: yes it is before post on stackoverflow i tried a lot of solutions and the minimum is to look into network part in my browser console ^^ !i see the post request but whitout Form data Part is clear ? So if you look the post i've update, you can't find the part in picture in my request with js.

Comment: Can you please post your form HTML on JsFiddle? Thank you

Comment: I have solved your problem in the Fiddle you have created

Comment: write the good solution on the post here dude and i validate your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way using form in html. On submit form call event.preventDefault, and then do that you want with

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //you code here
  });
});
```